# rss feed not always loading with FeedEk

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

This code seems to work well for NYT rss feeds but when I try to use CNN rss feeds sometimes it loads and sometimes it doesn't.  When it doesn't load I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rss' of null
at Object.success (FeedEk.min.js:1)
at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
at HTMLScriptElement.n.onload.n.onreadystatechange (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
```

```js
$('#divRss').FeedEk({FeedUrl:'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss'
                    });
```

```html
 <html>
      <head>
         <title>rss reader</title>

         <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FeedEk/3.0.0/css/FeedEk.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'</link>
         <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
         <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FeedEk/3.0.0/js/FeedEk.min.js'></script>
         <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
         
      </head>
      <body>

         <div id='divRss'></div>

      </body>
   </html>
```